# Best senior horse feed for post-colic surgery?

Tags: feeding, horses, senior-pet, equestrian

My horse has become picky post-colic surgery with his feed - Purina Senior Equine specifically. Luckily, we have been able to keep his weight on despite not being to eat hay because of his impaction. Any brands out there that have good nutritional balance without being a total sweet feed? Thank you!